# How do we remove labels bound to markers in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using: >

```
ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter() ,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
```

to create a marker and then create and bind a label to it as below:

```
ruler1label = new Label({ map: map });
ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
```

However, when removing the marker by: `ruler1.setMap(null)` which removes the marker but leaves the label behind. I tried unbinding the label to remove it by `ruler1label.setLabel(null)`; but it does not work. How can I remove these labels? I have appended a screenshot to make it clear.
[image]

Comment: Not sure why someone would want to close this as off-topic

Comment: Maybe because we don't know what `Label` this is?

Comment: Well the label associated with the first and only marker also does not get removed. If we set it like:   ruler1label = new Label({ map: map }); I am asking how do we unset it?

Comment: What I meant is *what Class is that Label*? Does it not provide a method to remove it? That's why you have 2 close votes. Nobody can reproduce the problem as we don't know what you are using.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `map` variable as well:

```
ruler1label.bindTo('map', ruler1, 'map');
```

Then this:

```
ruler1.setMap(null);
```

should hide both.

Comment: I tried binding the label like you showed, but then the label stays on the first clicked location as it is bound to the map,even if I drag the marker to some other point on map. It correctly updates the info though!